# Magento EE and Magento ECE both are same

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, magento2-enterprise

I'm planning to purchase **Magento 2 Enterprise Cloud Edition**.

**I have one doubt**

Is **Magento 2 Enterprise Edition(EE)** and **Magento 2 Enterprise Cloud Edition(ECE**) both are same?

**The Reason:**

**If Magento ECE support Magento EE code**

It took some months to completed the project so I think first we need to completed the project locally in Magento EE then purchase Magento ECE and move on our changes.

**If Magento ECE does not support Magento EE code**

I need to purchase now and start project from the scratch.

please advice me

Comment: Bilal, curious if you have learned anything since asking this question. facing similar case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magento Enterprise Cloud Edition is a *platform*, not a different Magento code base. If you use ECE, you run a regular Magento Enterprise Edition in the cloud, with some additional services.

### Here's the stack:

[image: Stack]

(click to enlarge)

Comment: thanks @fabian.  as per your answer I confirm like "completed the project in EE first after that purchase ECE and migrate our extension and theme from EE to ECE" am I correct?

Comment: You can do that. However, ECE also provides useful development tools, so it's a question of cost vs. value that you have to answer for yourself.

Comment: Magento shared the below blog recently where Magento stressing the point on significant improvements on deployment process. Please check this out. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/cloud/live/sens-data-over.html